# How to use Wifi adapter build-in my PC in Kali linux VMWARE

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux

How to use Wifi adapter build-in my PC in Kali linux VMWARE? Of course without USB wifi adapter.

BR

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you need an external USB adapter is when you run Kali on a VM, VMWare NATs your internet connection to the VM as a Wired Connection.

Dual booting your system and ensuring that the WiFi adapter has its drivers will enable you to use the PC's adapter for PenTesting.

Anyways, the advantages of using an external WiFI adapter which is designed for sniffing is these adapters are more powerful and have a lot of extra features.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the internal WiFi adapter of your computer with Kali in a virtual machine.

Usually to use a device from the host in the VM, you have to "virtually remove it from host" and "replug it in the VM as a USB device". It's exclusive, and **cannot be connected to both machines at the same time**. This feature is usable with **USB devices** (webcams, phones, flash drives, card readers and *WLAN/LAN adapters*).

Unlike with USB Wireless adapters, you can't "unplug" your internal adapter to plug it in the VM. The Virtualization software can "Bridge" or "NAT" your existing internet connection (whether it's wired or not) and the VM will see it as a wired LAN connection.